# Как изменить значения, получаю: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Считываю данные из Excel и фильтрую по содержимым ячеек.

```
x200 = df['Код ответа сервера']=='200 OK'
xp   = df['Код ответа сервера'].isnull()
c1   = df['Content-Type'].str.contains('text/html', na=False)
c2   = df['Content-Type'].isnull()

f1  = df[(x200 | xp)  & (c1|c2) ]
```

Дальше хочу изменить эти фильтрованные данные. Ошибок нет, но в терминале вижу

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

И данные не сохраняются. как исправить?

```
for i,(index,row) in enumerate(f1.iterrows()):
# for index, row in f1.iterrows():
    u1 = str(row['Уровень 1'])

if u1!='nan':
    f1.loc[index]['URL']=u1
    f1.loc[index]['Title']=u1
    f1.loc[index]['Category']=u1
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что должно произойти с исходным фреймом “df” - он должен остаться нетронутым или значения в нем тоже нужно поменять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
f1  = df[(x200 | xp)  & (c1|c2) ].copy()
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Если пользоваться `.loc`, то всё должно быть нормально. И не используйте `.iterrows` обычно без него можно обойтись:

```
...
u1 = ~df['Уровень 1'].isna()
f1 = df.loc[(x200|xp) & (c1|c2) & u1]
f1['URL'] = f1['Уровень 1']
f1['Title'] = f1['Уровень 1']
f1['Category'] = f1['Уровень 1']
```

Хотя нужно проверять, может быть нужно будет всё же при присваиваниях использовать `.loc`, запомнив предварительно битовую маску, а не сразу брать `.loc` от датафрейма.

Но это всё только если хотите менять именно исходный df, а если хотите копию - см. ответ MaxU.